# PDF rotation using python

Tags: python, pdf, rotation, ocr, vision

After rotate scanned pdf using python it works just fine but after sending the pdf to third party the third party still detect the pdf as a 90 deg pdf
is there any way to fix rotation and this problem

```
import PyPDF2
with open('input.pdf', 'rb') as file:
    # Create a PDF reader object
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file)

    # Create a PDF writer object
    writer = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()

    # Rotate each page by 90 degrees and add it to the writer object
    for page_num in range(len(reader.pages)):
        page = reader.pages[page_num]
        page.rotate(90)  # Rotate clockwise with negative angle
        writer.add_metadata({
            '/Rotate': '0'  # Set the desired rotation value (adjust as needed)
        })
        writer.add_page(page)

    # Write the rotated pages to a new PDF file
    with open('offffutput.pdf', 'wb') as output_file:
        writer.write(output_file)
```

Comment: can u give me an example please

Comment: yes i tried this 
cpdf -rotate-contents 90 in.pdf -o out.pdf
but error is appear that " No such option: -r  "